# Make div inherit height of sibling img - possible?

Tags: css

```
<div id="holder">
    <img src="blah.jpg" width="xxx" height="yyy">
    <div id="stuff">waffle</div>
</div>
```

Where xxx and yyy are generated in PHP based on the size of the image being shown.

I'd like #stuff to be the same size, to overlay it completely.  The overlaying and the width are trivial with CSS, but I don't know how to set the height of the div, without resorting to an inline style.

height:100% doesn't work, as you need to have an explicitly set height on the parent element, which I don't.

Any options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way with absolute positioning. Though it may not be ideal as `#holder` would have to be `inline-block` or floated

```css
#holder {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

#stuff {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" width="xxx" height="yyy">
    <div id="stuff">waffle</div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that you need `display: inline-block` or a `float` to get `#holder` to wrap to the size of the image.

Comment: That worked perfectly, I don't think I ever knew you could size things by supplying opposing positions like that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, assuming `#holder` is just going to be the size of the image and `#stuff` should be the same size as `#holder`:

```
#holder {
  position: relative;
}

#stuff {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```